# Responsive site menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://nggalaxy.ru/en/about-us/ - here is the example of exact behaviour to be implemented. When you scroll down the page, the side menu disappears and appears on top of the page.
How it can be realized using bootstrap for example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of raw Javascript + jQuery making this happen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function(){ 

var a = 112;
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
if(pos > a) {
    $("menu").css({
                position: 'fixed'
            });
}
else {
    $("menu").css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top:'600px'
            });
}
});
</script>
```

This will add a CSS style if the user scrolled 112 pixel down. Like this you can create all styles for your menu.

In General: Use javascript to check on what scroll-position the user is, and append the styles or classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. Is there another approaches for this? Actually I need to implement this behaviour by using Bootstrap.